# dotnet restore file matching

Tags: .net-core, azure-devops, azure-yaml-pipelines

My folder structure for a code base looks like this

- src

  - Test

    - Users.Services
  - Users.Services
  - Users.Domain
  - Users.Infra

Now, if want to restore for only the Users projects and not the Test projects, I cannot get the file matching to work.

I have tried different exclude combinations. This is part of my yaml file, but this doesn't work. It fails with a failed pattern match.

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Restore
  inputs:
    projects: '!src/Test/**/*.csproj;src/**/*.csproj'
    command: restore
    verbosityRestore: Minimal
```

Any idea of what I am missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this:

```yaml
    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: Restore
      inputs:
        projects: |
            src/**/*.csproj
            !src/Test/**/*.csproj
        command: restore
        verbosityRestore: Minimal
```

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/file-matching-patterns?view=azure-devops) you have link to pattern matching.

And pipe is simply multiline. You will find example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/dotnet-core-cli?view=azure-devops#build)

Comment: What does the pipe do ?  And is there a reference you can link to ? :)

Comment: Ok it worked. I will make a pull request for the file matching reference documentation.

Comment: But it's kinda funny, because looking at the documentation, there is heavy use for the ! as a separator for a new pattern. Eg.: 

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'push'
    searchPatternPush: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/*.nupkg;!$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/*.Tests.nupkg'
    feedPublish: 'FabrikamFeed'

ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/dotnet-core-cli?view=azure-devops#push